# Can't verify account via phone

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to add an add-on to my heroku project, but it needs verification by phone number. But the phone numbers of my country is not supported (Ukraine), so I'm getting an error `This number is not supported.` My account has already been verified using credit card. This additional verification is required to use this addon though.

What should I do with it and how to resolve this problem? Only this add-on is fit to me, so I can't get alternative one.

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was only solved for me through opening a support ticket on Heroku.
Someone from their team then manually verified the account for me